# HTML pyramid-like tables

Tags: html, html-table

Yesterday a friend has shown me a weird problem he has encountered in his classes. He could not make a pyramid-like table(as shown in my jsfiddle link below).
I've never really dealt with html tables much, but I thought this was just about the program they were using being stupid. But when I tried writing html for it myself, I saw it was more than that...

This is what I was trying:
http://jsfiddle.net/5aDkL/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">A</td>
        <td colspan="1">B</td>
        <td colspan="2">C</td>
        <td colspan="1">D</td>
        <td colspan="1">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">F</td>
        <td colspan="2">G</td>
        <td colspan="2">H</td>
        <td colspan="1">I</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">J</td>
        <td colspan="2">K</td>
        <td colspan="2">L</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the table doesn't look anything like you would expect(unless you know about this already).
So after some web searching, I came up with the following, which works fine(with a single line of css):
http://jsfiddle.net/SzWHX/

```
<table border="1">
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">A</td>
        <td colspan="1">B</td>
        <td colspan="2">C</td>
        <td colspan="1">D</td>
        <td colspan="1">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">F</td>
        <td colspan="2">G</td>
        <td colspan="2">H</td>
        <td colspan="1">I</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">J</td>
        <td colspan="2">K</td>
        <td colspan="2">L</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I was wondering, is there a better way to code this?
I mean, those empty col elements just look silly there, right?
So if anyone can enlighten me, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simpler way at present. This is a good example of a case where the `col` element is really needed (for the intended styling). The reason is that otherwise there is no way to refer to the 3rd and 4th column in CSS, since no table cell occupies only one slot in such a column.

In theory, the `:nth-column()` pseudo-class would let us do the styling without the `col` elements, but it’s really work in progress, being planned ([CSS Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/)).

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway. I just thought it's obvious from the colspans that there should be 6 columns, so those kinda seem unneeded...

Comment: Yes, the browser can calculate that there are 6 columns. But there is no CSS selector that refers to the columns, unless you have the `col` elements.

Answer (score 2):

That "pyramid" looks really ugly:

[image: OP's Pyramid]

Especially obvious when you look at the table without borders:

[image: OP's Pyarmid without borders]

Wouldn't a better compromise be to add the necessary empty (`&nbsp;`) cells so that the spacing is correct?  I set all the columns to a width of 20px, you can do this with css without use of `col` in the below example if desired.

[image: Pyramid with extra empty cells]

[image: Pyramid with extra empty cells without borders]

One last comparison:

[image]